# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after using maven for the first time?

Tags: java, maven, soap

I've been creating a soap server with java for my company and I just recently switched over to using Bone-CP and Maven to import all the required 3rd party programs. After I finished implementing bone-CP I used the server command

```
jar -cvfm SoapServer.jar manifest.txt SoapServer
```

And when I transfered it to my server and tried to run it I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SoapServer/SoapServer (wrong name: com/test/SoapServer/SoapServer)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

The only think I can think of causing the problem is that maven doesn't package the required JARs with the program? If that's the case do I just need to download them and add them to the class path?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need all of your dependencies to be packed in the executable jar then configure your pom like

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
               <mainClass>com.something.YourMainClass</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

above block will add all the library in lib/ to classpath in manifest classpath entry

and to copy all the dependencies to lib directory

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add another classpathPrefix entry in maven-jar-plugin?
Like:
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
<classpathPrefix>config/</classpathPrefix>
I would like to have an external folder called config to store a properties file for me perform changes in this file without needing to change the properties file that would be inside the packaged jar file in config folder.

Comment: I had that requirement and I ended up modifying plugin locally before sometime, I should have pull requested, What do you need to add to class path entries other than dependencies ?

Comment: For example,
inside jar I have:
-- config/bioagents.properties

It's not viable for an user open the jar file to change the properties file.

As I saw that we can put some dependencies in an external file, not packaged in a jar, I would like to do the same for config/bioagents.properties.

Putting in an external directory (not packaged in a jar file). Thus, a simple user can change the properties of my program easily.

Comment: Usually user changes properties file while running the application, as opposed to while building the Jar, but still if that is the use case, this can easily be done via maven assembly plugin, configure it to pack all dependencies and on top of that you could include file from your File system at relative path in your Jar file being built

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will try this.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html is a quick start configuration