# Eclipse + Maven + Spring Application: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

There are many stackoverflow questions around this subject but, they surprisingly don't seem to address my situation.

I have validated the following things:

1. No conflicting Spring libraries. I am using the latest releases in
   Maven repository
2. I am using Maven plugin for eclipse and running it
       in eclipse using run class as Java Application. No assembly needed
3. I have manually checked the jar file in my local Maven repository. It has EnvironmentCapable.class in the path it is expected
4. It is a simple application which is basically code from Chapter 1 of
   Spring in Action book

My POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.springinaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>knights</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>knights</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The main class code that does not run.

```
package com.springinaction.knights;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

public class KnightMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(KnightConfig.class);

        Knight knight = (Knight)context.getBean(Knight.class);
        knight.embarkOnQuest();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Gist of error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840367/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-after-using-maven-for-the-first-time

Comment: I think you are mixing some jars of spring 3 and spring 4 as mentioned class in in spring 3

Comment: your configuration works fine with me. apparently it seems that your class path contains spring version which less than of 3.1.x.

Comment: Do you have KnightConfig class in your project? And what about your knight bean? Where are they?

Comment: @MosheArad KnightConfig, Knight and Quest are all in the same package and actually same folder of the project.

Comment: @kuhajeyan In my local Maven repository, there are few jar files belonging to 3.1.2 RELEASE that were pulled due to earlier configuration but, doesn't build specifically look for 4.3.2.RELEASE jars as I have mentioned them explicitly?

Comment: @kuhajeyan I just checked my build path configuration in eclipse. Maven has configured it to point to exact release folders and not repository in general. So, spring jars from 3.1.2 version should not be referred either during build or, run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got in your local repository some old artifacts you wish to get rid of, just do this:

1. On command line go to folder where your pom.xml is located
2. type and execute the next command: `dependency:purge-local-repository`

That command will clean your local repository, from dependencies that are being used in your project.

Look at the description from Maven website:

[image]

Now, to that:

1. On command line go to folder where your pom.xml is located
2. type and execute the next command: `dependency:copy-dependencies`

Look at the description from Maven website:

[image]

This command will pull from remote repository the necessary dependencies to your local repository.

Comment: Copying the dependencies to my local project target folder from the maven's local repository has resolved this issue. Does this mean that it is a safe practice to copy the dependencies to my project's folder always? I am new to this so, please bear with me here.

Comment: You don't need to copy dependencies from maven local repository to your target folder, it's considered to be a bad practice. In order to sync maven to your project, use the m2e plugin if you're using eclipse editor. Instead, I like to use mvn eclipse:eclipse which is the eclipse plugin but this project is discontinued and should not be used any more.

Comment: The command `dependency:copy-dependencies` copied the dependencies from my local maven repository to my project's target\dependency folder. That is the reason I am asking.